# "Android Studio" debugging - display variables as hexadecimal

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I've recently moved from Eclipse to Android Studio, and it looks great. However, I can't seem to find how to display variables in debugging mode as hexadecimal values instead of decimal values.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: [Xcode version](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35238651/3681880) of this question.

Answer (score 20):

I was wondering [the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29935784/view-values-as-hexidecimal-by-default-while-debugging-in-android-studio), especially how to do this by default as @adnako asked. I finally found an answer so I will post here, too.

## Manually change a single value

Right click > View as... > Hex

[image]

## Display all values as hex by default

Right click > Custimize Data Views... > Show hex values for primitives > Apply

[image]

(Note: these images are from Android Studio 1.2)

Comment: In AS 1.4 (and 2.0) the "customize data views" option is not visible for me when inspecting a variable. There is however a global setting under "Build, Execution, Deployment -> Debugger -> Data Views -> Java -> Show hex value for primitives". Easiest is to just open settings and type "hex" in the search box.

Comment: Not available for native debugger.

Answer (score 4):

In the debug window, right click on the value you would like to view in hex and choose `View as -> Hex`. This can be done in the `Variables` or `Watches` views.

Comment: so in eclipse if we hover over a variable name it shows a tooltip sort of a thing with the value in it. Is there anything in android studio similar to this? Rather than adding all the variables to watches.

Comment: If you hold down Ctrl (on windows) while hovering over a variable it shows you the current value. You can even do this when not debugging and it will show you the initialization value of the variable.

Comment: How to do to use this behavior as default?

Comment: @adnako I don't know if you can, have never seen any setting to that effect.

Comment: Hehe, has a few quirks yes, but I'll take it over Eclipse any day ;)