# View values as hexidecimal by default while debugging in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, settings, default

My question is similar to ["Android Studio" debugging - display variables as hexadecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447013/android-studio-debugging-display-variables-as-hexadecimal), but I want to know how to make this the default setting.

I know how to change the setting for individual values:

[image]

but for checking the values of all the characters in long strings, this becomes tedious. Unicode characters are much more readable when displayed in hex. Is there any way to set this as the default in Android Studio? I looked in File > Settings > Debugger but I didn't see anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click to get the context menu and choose "Custimize Data Views...".

[image]

Then check "Show hex values for primitives".

[image]

Now the values should automatically display in hexadecimal without having to manually change each one.

[image]

Comment: Is this the best there is?

Comment: Not available for native debugger.