# Android Studio see byte[] as string in debugger

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea

I am trying to debug some data, and I have a byte[] that I know has text in it. But I can't figure out how to view it as text, or even get a hex representation that I could convert to text. I have tried creating a custom type converter that uses 'new String(this)', but then it just shows 'instance of java.lang.String'

Note: I am using Android Studio, which is build on IntelliJ

Comment: Is creating a new watch `new String(nameOfYourBytesArrayVariable)` not an option?

Comment: I tried that, it complained that it couldn't resolve String, and if I used java.lang.String it complained that it couldn't resolve java.lang.String. I am using android studio if that makes a difference.

Comment: As you asked for presenting a hex-representation, maybe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447013/android-studio-debugging-display-variables-as-hexadecimal) is helpful to you as well

Comment: According to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25057447/how-to-put-a-watchsee-how-a-variable-is-modified-in-android-studio) Android Studio should support wach variables too, however, the execution needs to be within the visibility-context of the respective variable. If it is defined in a method locally, while debugging you need to be inside that method to actually be able to use a watch. [This page](https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html) has also good amount of infos on how to debug in general with Android Studio

Comment: @RomanVottner I want to see the byte[] as a string. I can look at the hex value for each byte individually, but I can't figure out how to get a string with ALL the hex values that I could easily convert to a string, without having to manually type in each byte.

Comment: @RomanVottner I can set a break point and view the data as a byte[] I just can't figure out how to view it as a UTF-8 encoded string from that byte[].

Answer (score 5):

1. Customize String Data View

[image: String Data View]

2. View as string

[image: View as string]

Comment: I should be like that but your solution are crashing and skipping debugging but for `ByteString` i got String after adding `utf8()` in both renderer. thanks