# new String(bytes[]) in watch window of Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, debugging

While I debug and I want to watch one **byte array**, I add it to watch window of Android Studio.

I used `new String(bytes)` to watch it's content, but it shows  `new String(bytes) = ""`, actually bytes contains values.

what strange here is that, I make a call of
`ConvertTool.convertToString(bytes, s)`, it works well. It implemented like below. Anyone know what's happened here?

```
   public static String convertToString(byte[] object,String encode_type){
    return new String(object,encode_type);
   }
```

[image: debug screen shot]

**Version of Android Studio**: Android Studio 3.0.1
Build #AI-171.4443003, built on November 10, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b08 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.12.6

Comment: Did you checked [Android Studio see byte\[\] as string in debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31466512/4391450) ? You should add your studio version too. It could be a bug in the watcher.

Comment: I have tried that, its behavior like I mentioned before. If I used `new String` it shows empty string, it works well if make a call of `convertToString` @AxelH