# UTF-8 in Android compared to definition of UTF-8

Tags: android, encoding, utf-8

i got a question to UTF-8 in Android. I Need to store a String into a Byte[] in UTF-8 Format.

So far so good. Here is my code where the user type into a editText and this should be stored into a Byte[] in UTF-8 Format:

```
idString = editId.getText().toString();
byte[] valueId = idString.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

now if I type for example the number: 1

it should be stored as UTF-8 unit: 31

but it is stored as the decimal value: 49

I dont get the glue what my failure is, so can anybody help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with hex and decimal values. It is stored in a format known as the ASCII table. The number 1 is stored as decimal 49 or hex 31.

This might help you http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Yeah thank you that helped a bit. So it is right if debug shows me 49 it is stored as 0x31 in my Array? In bits 0011 0001?

Comment: Yes, the 0x notation shows it is a hex value and not an integer one. You can use online hex to integer conversion tools, http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter , or you can view the value in debug mode directly, posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447013/android-studio-debugging-display-variables-as-hexadecimal

Comment: Thank you so all worked i just got confused because of the debug window.

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: Now i got one last question to that Topic maybe u know the answer, too. If i want to Display that values into a TextView i go for it with: `Arrays.toString(valueId)` but it Shows again only the decimal view. Is there a possible easy way to Show as 0x31?

Comment: I think the Integer.toHexString is what you are looking for, you might need to add the 0x as a string.

Comment: You've identified the problem but this has nothing to do with ASCII. See [UTF-8](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf8-1).